# MySql InnoDB tables are missing after restarting

Tags: mysql, innodb, windows, mysql-workbench

I had a MySql database with a few InnoDB tables. After restarting the server, and starting MySql Server again, I connected to the MySql Server using MySql Workbench, and couldn't see the database at all (it even doesn't show up empty, it's just not there). It's important to note that the server was brutally shut down (I had no choice), so maybe MySql Server wasn't closed normally, and it caused a problem.

I am new to MySQL area with innoDB. Any help is really appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Regards, Ron

Comment: If MySQL is running, please run `SHOW ENGINES;` and look for the row with `InnoDB`. Look at the `Support` column. Does it say `YES`, `NO`, `DEFAULT`, or `DISABLED` ???

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA It says DEFAULT.

Comment: Run `show variables like  'datadir';`. What does it say ???

Comment: It says: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\data\, but I checked and saw that my database isn't there...

Comment: Oh you are running MySQL for Windows. Please run this query: `select table_schema DB,SUM(data_length)/POWER(1024,2) DAT,SUM(index_length)/POWER(1024,2) NDX ,SUM(data_length+index_length)/POWER(1024,2) DBSIZE FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('informatio_schema','mysql') GROUP BY table_schema;`. It should return how much data the MySQL Instance can see IN Gigabytes. What does it return? Another question: Did you have MySQL 5.6 running before ???

Comment: It returns: 

information_schema 0 0.009765625 0.009765625
performance_schema 0 0 0

Comment: and I have MySql 5.6 installed, but I don't think I've ever run it..

Answer (score 2):

If you have MySQL 5.6 running before, then the MySQL data is located in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\`

If you had recently installed MySQL 5.7, that instance has its own MySQL data in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\data\.`

You need to migrate the data from MySQL 5.6 into MySQL 5.7.

If you are not sure what what version of MySQL was actually running on your Windows Server, here are two things you must investigate:

## INVESTIGATION #1

- Goto to Windows Explorer
- Navigate to `C:\Program Files\MySQL`

## INVESTIGATION #2

- For every folder under `C:\Program Files\MySQL`

  - Go inside the subfolder `MySQL 5.x`
  - Locate the file `my.ini`

Whichever folder has `my.ini` was in the installed version of MySQL

If none of them has `my.ini`, you have to dig a little deeper

## INVESTIGATION #3

- Click `Start` -> `Control Panel` -> `Administrative Tools` -> `Services`
- Once the `Services` panel is open, scroll down alphabetically to MySQL.
- Right click on `MySQL`
- Choose Properties

This will show you the path to the MySQL binary it called and the `my.ini` associated with it. If it does not show a `my.ini`, then the `my.ini` should appear in the parent directory of the executable.

If this does not work, then you will have to look inside MySQL Workbench for the original connection settings you were connecting with.

Comment: None of those directories have the MySQL data that disappeared.

Comment: Have you tried doing a full file system search for the file "ibdata1"? In case the server had a custom datadir previously.

Answer (score 0):

Using the server admin section on the right hand side of workbench can you see if the MySQL server is running? Using the workbench server admin can you check/test connections? Have you viewed the server logs (from the same menu)?

I don't know that a shutdown of a running server should cause all the data to go missing. Far more likely is that your MySQL workbench isn't pointing to the correct directories. Using the 'manage server instances' check the path to the ini files. Have a look in the MySQL DATA directory - just as a quick check that there is a database there!

I must say workbench isn't as good as the old admin front end but it should give you a fair amount of information.

Comment: Well, the data directory doesn't have my database in there.
It's super strange, but it seems like my database is gone.
Luckily, I have a backup.