# How can I check the path of my.ini, through the command line?

Tags: mysql, windows, command-line, mysqld, my.ini

I would like to know, if possible, how to display (using the command line) the path to `my.ini` used by the server.

I am using MySQL 5.6 inside a windows IIS.

I have the following:

- `Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my-default.ini`
- `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini`.

For sure, the server is using the second one. Is the path stored in any variable inside mysql server variables?
I was checking some [system variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html) but I couldn't find it.

Any ideas?

---

UPDATE
After Ronaldo's post I ran a --help and this is what I found:

```
...
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
C:\Windows\my.ini 
C:\Windows\my.cnf 
C:\my.ini 
C:\my.cnf 
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini 
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.cnf

The following groups are read: mysql client
The following options may be given as the first argument:
--print-defaults        Print the program argument list and exit.
...
```

The strange thing is that I don't have none of these files. I sit to display hided files on each folder.

So, I took a look to this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56767/mysql-innodb-tables-are-missing-after-restarting/56776#56776) and I followed the steps.
Finally I arrived at the window **MySQL56 Properties(Local Computer)**.
I could read:

```
Path to executable: 
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file
```

BUT,
if we click over it with the mouse's right button and choose Select All, this is what we have:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe" 
--defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini" MySQL56
```

So that replies my question.

Comment: locate your service and see properties it would display which file is the default one being used by the service. Moreover you may have to look for process details to to check at command line of windows. On linux you may use ps aux|grep mysql to see and on windows use the above method. Hope it helps

Comment: You can specify --defaults-file=<path_to_file> to make **absolutely** sure that you're using a given file - I issued the command "`show variables like '%file%';`" and got nothing - I also searched for variables like "`cnf`" (Linux) - again, no joy. The `my-default`.ini is AIUI, a file that is copied to the operational location on install - it's up to you then to modify the defaults as per your system and I'm 99% certain that it's never read on server startup.

Comment: HI Nawaz, this is what i did. That is why I told I am sure the system is using the second file.   But I am not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mysqld.exe` does not report the location of the my.ini it is using. I learned over the years that the `my.ini` file is supposed to be in the parent folder of the data and bin directories:

- `Feb 06, 2012` : [MySQL Database and Table Loss](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12247/mysql-database-and-table-loss/12366#12366)
- `Jan 14, 2014` : [MySql InnoDB tables are missing after restarting](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56767/mysql-innodb-tables-are-missing-after-restarting/56776#56776) (See `INVESTIGATION #2`)

What can you do form the command line ?

From the command line, run this

```
C:\> mysqld --help --verbose > C:\mysqld_options.txt
notepad C:\mysqld_options.txt
```

Go look for the line that says

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
```

The line underneath will tell you the places where mysqld looks for `my.ini`

If you don't see one, then use the parent folder of the data and bin directory to make one.

**Give it a Try !!!**

Comment: Please Check an Update.

Comment: I have `my.ini` inside `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\``, not inside `Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\`` where bin is located.